# Clustering Weka java API

Tags: java

While implementing simple kmeans clustering via weka java API, how to select  attributes based on which clustering is to be performed. I have tried following line of code:

```
FilteredClusterer fc=new FilteredClusterer();
String[] options=new String[2];
options[0]="-R";
options[1]="1";
Remove remove=new Remove();
remove.setOptions(options);
remove.setInputFormat(train);
fc.setFilter(remove);
fc.setClusterer(clusterer);
fc.buildClusterer(train);`
```

but an error is generated and it says `arrayIndexOutOfBound`

Comment: You could try this Instances newData = Filter.useFilter(train, remove); before building the clusterer to find out if the problem has to do with your filter and attributes.

Comment: yes i did even this and after that typed clusterer.buildClusterer(newData) with the same exception generated